# Call batch from python - environment issues

Tags: python, windows, batch-file

I want to create a batch file using python, run that script and then execute more python code.

The batch script itself is simple, it just sets a few environment variables and launches an application with one argument. It looks similar to this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set PROG=C:\foo\bar.cmd
set MYVAR1=PIRATES
set MYVAR2=NINJAS
set MYVAR3=KITTENS
set MYVAR4=LASERS
"%PROG%" "C:\foo\some_file"
endlocal
@echo off
```

The batch file is created correct, but my problem is:

When calling this script via python, it doesn't work. `bar.cmd` just quits with an error that indicates missing environment variables.

But if i launch the same batch file manually, everything is working just fine.

So there is some difference when it comes to the environment variables when launched via python or directly and i don't know how to fix this.

I tried to set the environment variables in the python-code too, right before generating and executing the batch. I used

```
os.environ['MYVAR1']='PIRATES'
```

and

```
os.putenv('MYVAR1', 'PIRATES')
```

with all variables - it didn't work.

I also tried different methods of calling the batch file, like

```
os.system()
```

or

```
os.popen()
```

or

```
subprocess.Popen()
```

without success. The batch is created and called correct, it quits with an error concerning the environment vars, but a manual execution of the batch script works every time.

Why is this happening? How to set the environment correct?

Btw, i'm working with Win 7 (64bit) and Python 2.7.

#### Update:

It's working now! This is what happened:

I continued my work on this script and to my big surprise i found that my batch-script wasn't working anymore. Not when called from python - and not when called manually (using cmd.exe).

I am sure that it has been working before, so i tried to find out what could have gone wrong.

I can't explain what really was going on, but to me it seems like i have tried around with various console windows and various calls to get the target application running - and that could have set an environment variable that was active when i posted this issue.

After rebooting the system and continuing work on the next day, neither the python nor the batch worked - but i managed to log the environment variables on various steps/places and recogniced a variable that i hadn't included in my script.

Long story short: ...used all the correct environment variables right in python, don't need to call  a batch file now anymore. I'm just running the wanted commands and everything is fine.

Lesson learned: ...if using environment variables, don't try too many things parallel.

Comment: Have you tried the [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) option in subprocess?

Comment: `os.environ()` is not a `callable`.....have you noticed that?

Comment: If you run your bat file from python it will just set the env variables in the  chid, not the parent process!

Comment: Please provide a complete example that fails. I assume the batch script you show above is called `foo.cmd`, and it's running some `bar.cmd` that fails for some reason, but you don't show use what `bar.cmd` does or how it fails, or how you're running `foo.cmd` in Python.

Comment: @Mike: Yes. Didn't do anything.

Comment: @ha9u63ar: Don't know what you want to say? I'm not calling  `os.environ()` - i'm setting `os.environ[]`.

Comment: @eryksun: Sorry if that was too little information.I can't provide an example of

Comment: @eryksun: [...continued, because of enter...] I can't provide an example of `bar.cmd`. It's part of a big application and basically a script that can route a lot of in- and outputs. I don't really understand all of its features, i'm just using one of it - this simple call with one file as an argument. The error is clearly not in `bar.cmd`. To your question how i launch my python-script: I'm running a command window (admin mode) and just executing the .py-file. Do you think that might have an influence?

Comment: A batch script is run by cmd.exe. If you run it via `os.system` or the defaults for `subprocess.Popen`, then the process gets a copy of the current environment. If it in turns starts another program, then that program gets a copy of its environment, and so on.

Comment: @eryksun: Thanks! This somehow helped me in getting my script working - problem solved, case closed.